# How to print list elements with non-ASCII characters in functional style?

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, non-ascii-characters, python-unicode

I'm trying to deal with strings containing non-ASCII characters in Python 2.7.
Specifically, I want to print the elements of the following list in order to display their external representation:

```
foo = "mädchen wörter mutter".split()
```

Like this:

```
>>> for x in foo:
...     print x
... 
mädchen
wörter
mutter
```

Except I need to do it in functional style. But if I try the following, without using `print`, it's the internal representation that is shown:

```
>>> [x for x in foo]
['m\xc3\xa4dchen', 'w\xc3\xb6rter', 'mutter']
```

I tried using `print` like this, but it obviously doesn't work either as this prints the whole list instead of each separate element:

```
>>> print [x for x in foo]
['m\xc3\xa4dchen', 'w\xc3\xb6rter', 'mutter']
```

And placing `print` inside the square brackets returns a syntax error:

```
>>> [print x for x in foo]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [print x for x in foo]
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I then tried using a function that would print `x`:

```
>>> def show(x):
...     print(x)
... 

>>> [show(x) for x in foo]
mädchen
wörter
mutter
[None, None, None]
```

This almost works, except for the `[None, None, None]` at the end (where does that comes from?).

Is there a functional way to just output something like this:

```
>>> [*do_something* for x in foo]
mädchen
wörter
mutter
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Is there a functional way to just output something like this:" - No. You're creating a list there, and that list is going to get shown.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "*functional style*". What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Robᵩ Neither am I to be honest. Maybe I should have said "functional form" instead. I was taught that `[x for x in foo]` was the "functional" form of `for x in foo: x`

Comment: Thanks. I'd never heard either of terms before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `string.join(..)` ?

```
print "\n".join(foo)
```

---

Also, note that what you are using is called: `list comprehension`. And typically, list comprehensions are used in a sense of `map` -- that is without side-effects. Calling `show(..)` on every elements, and discarding the result of list comprehension is not how it is *supposed* to be used..

---

> This almost works, except for the [None, None, None] at the end (where does that comes from?).

It comes from the return value of list-comprehension. It is `show(..)` *applied* to each element, and since the function return `None` you see 3 `None`s.

---

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick! I did read a post on list comprehension earlier with examples that looked a bit like mine, but didn't realise that was what I was doing here. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

```
def show(x):
    print(x)

[show(x) for x in foo]
mädchen
wörter
mutter
[None, None, None]
```

will actually work if you write it in a script. When you write that in the interpreter, every time the function is called, value is printed and in the end, the list is printed too. List won't be printed if you write the same code in a .py file.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked, thanks. In this case I need to do it using the interpreter, but this will be helpful to know.